# How to post iframe codes in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I'm trying to post iframe codes in textarea but I think PHP not allowing this process. Is there any way to post all data as text?

Btw I'm using enctype="multipart/form-data" for the form, because I'm posting some photos and other stuff.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense (to me). Can you rephrase and post some sample code showing what you're trying to do?

Comment: I have a form which contains multiple selecting item, text area, file upload form and I'm using one this forms elements (a textarea) to post youtube iframe code to save in database or pringting to a new page with other form elements. When I'm adding iframe code and send data, my php page stop responsing.

Comment: Okay, do you have error reporting turned on? If so, what do the errors say? If not, check your server `error.log`. And you're going to have to post your code. We cannot help without it.

Comment: I'm trying it on localhost and Opera says: "Opera detected unusual code on this page and blocked it to protect your personal information (for example, passwords, phone numbers, and credit cards)." 

Is that mean my code is working but browser is blocking it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment, you mentioned that:

> I'm trying it on localhost and Opera says: "Opera detected unusual code on this page and blocked it to protect your personal information (for example, passwords, phone numbers, and credit cards)." Is that mean my code is working but browser is blocking it?

And indeed, it does. Most modern browsers implement [XSS protection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-XSS-Protection), which will refuse to render HTML fragments which appear to be copied from the request. This is a crude, but effective way of blocking certain types of [cross-site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) (XSS) attacks.

To disable this feature, your web application can set the header:

```
X-XSS-Protection: 0
```

Alternatively, you may want to consider refactoring your application so that users do not need to input raw HTML. For example, if you want to allow users to embed Youtube videos, ask for the URL of the video and generate the embed code in your application.

Comment: Thank you so much. Absolutely I will reconsider to refactoring my application but as you can guess from my question, I'm very new at coding and I just wanted to test my codes.